# Customising UIButtonType

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I've a `MKPinAnnotationView` which has a `leftCalloutAccessoryView` that receives a `UIButton`.

```
let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView()

pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
pinView.canShowCallout = true
pinView.draggable = true

let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
button.addTarget(self, action: "navigateUserFromCoordinates:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

return pinView
```

I'm trying to customise the `UIButtonType` to display an icon of mine but I couldn't determine how to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView()
pinView.pinTintColor = .blueColor()
pinView.canShowCallout = true
pinView.draggable = true

let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage"), forState: .Normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.addTarget(self, action: "navigateUserFromCoordinates:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

return pinView
```